# How to mock concrete object in a template type exported from a dll?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googlemock

I have an application `Application` object type exported from a dll (dynamic link library) like so,

```
//App.h
class __declspec(dllexport) Application
{
    Utility utility;
public:
    Application();
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
    ~Application();
};
```

It "has a" utility that it uses for providing some crucial functionality, through its Foo and Bar exports. As the utility is concrete, I followed the [mock non-virtual methods using templates](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) given in GMock primer. So I've made my app look like the following,

```
//App.h - modified
template <class Utility>
class __declspec(dllexport) Application
{
    Utility utility;
public:
    Application();
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
    ~Application();
};
```

Now that I've templatized my type, in production I will use, `Application<ConcreteUtility>` and for testing I wanted to use, `Application<MockUtility>`. the .cpp file for the app looks like the following now, specializing for `Application<ConcreteUtility>`

```
//.cpp
template class Application<ConcreteUtility>;
Application<ConcreteUtility>::Application() {/*construct app with the concrete utility*/}
Application<ConcreteUtility>::Foo() {/*implement Application's foo using the concrete utility*/}
Application<ConcreteUtility>::Bar {/*implement Application's bar using the concerete utility*/}
Application<ConcreteUtility>::~Application() {/*destroy the Application*/ }
```

I've written a unit test application, that will link to my application dll at load time (.h and .lib import library). As I'm using GMock framework I've mocked the utility like so,

```
class MockUtility
{
public:
    /*mock all public methods of utility that the application could have possibly used*/
    MOCK_METHOD1(FuncUsingANetworkConnection, void(int));
    MOCK_METHOD0(FuncUsingADatabase, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(FuncReadingAndWritingFromDisk, int());
    MOCK_METHOD2(FuncManipulatingWindowsRegistry, int(long, long));
    MOCK_METHOD0(FuncSomeMoreUnreliableResource, int());
};
```

Now, In my test fixture, I've instantiated, `Application<MockUtility>`. It compiles, but while linking it is not able to find the definitions for, `Application<MockUtility>::Application()` - the constructor, `Application<MockUtility>::Foo()` - the foo for `Application<MockUtility>` and `Application<MockUtility>::Bar()` and  `Application<MockUtility>::~Application()`. It starts to complain here.

I can see that it is indeed not defined anywhere, but how do I make this work ? I cannot refactor and extract an interface out of this utility, as it is too hairy. But I wanted to unit test this application dll's functionality somehow.

I did not want to pollute the App's implementation, with the unit testing stuff and writing an implementation separately for `Application<MockUtility>`. Even If I can do that, I cannot manage to bring all the changes in the app to this new implementation I write every time the app changes.

I'm not sure if this will make any sense but I will go ahead and ask: I want the compiler and linker to understand that `Application<MockUtility>` is just the  Application with the implementation for `utility` from the `MockUtility` I've written.

Is this thing even possible ? 
If not, how can I mock calls made on this `utility` object ?